# passing a function to replace with regex with match as arg

Tags: javascript, regex

This javascript code needs to pass the invoke the function `convert` and use its returned value to replace every match. But it is not sending the `cid` value to the `convert` function. Any idea how to? Thanks

```js
const convert = function (cid) {
    console.log('got: ' + cid); // got NAN
    const converted = Math.round(Number(cid) * 16.3871);
    console.log(converted);
    return converted
};
    return myStr.replace(/(\d{3})/g, convert('$1'));
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you post the complete function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't invoke the `convert` function as the second `replace` parameter. It will be invoked automatically and pass `$1` match on its own as 1st `convert` argument.
And the second `return` is incorrect (out of function).

```
const convert = function (cid) {
      console.log('got: ' + cid); // got NAN
      const converted = Math.round(Number(cid) * 16.3871);
      console.log(converted);
      return converted;
    };

var someString = 'abc134def';

console.log(someString.replace(/(\d{3})/g, convert));
```